# How to handle "Action not found" with Dependency Injection Play framework 2.4

Tags: error-handling, playframework, dependency-injection

I override class `HttpErrorHandler` on Injection Dependency concept and try to handles routing page. I don't need the `Action not found` page presented when routing page of URL incorrect,but it must to presented by specify page route on `view.html.error.notFoundPage()` of `HttpPageErrorHandler`. Figure such as below when try to access URL didn't included with parameter

`http://localhost:9000/adminlanding`

Routing page assigned as

`GET /adminlanding/:userId/:ip/:dateFound/           controllers.DashboardAdmin.landing(userId: String, ip : String, dateFound : String)`

HttpPageErrorHandler handles `Action not found`

```
class HttpPageErrorHandler @Inject() (router: Router) extends HttpErrorHandler {
   private def errorHandler = Play.maybeApplication.fold[HttpErrorHandler](DefaultHttpErrorHandler)(_.errorHandler)

   def onClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String) : Future[Result]= { 
       statusCode match {
         case Status.NOT_FOUND => 
                Future.successful(NotFound(views.html.errors.notFoundPage(request)))
         case clientError if statusCode >= 400 && statusCode < 500 =>
                Future.successful(Forbidden(views.html.errors.notFoundPage(request)))
       }
   } 

   def onServerError(request: RequestHeader, exception: Throwable): Future[Result] = {
     errorHandler.onServerError(request, exception)
   }

}
```

Application.conf declares configuration to call injection class

`play.http.HttpErrorHandler = RequestHandler`

After run command line with `sbt run` stills show `Action not found` page.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
play.http.errorHandler = "global.HttpPageErrorHandler"
```

or whatever is your package .